# how to show images from array of posts data in jquery ajax request in laravel?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-8

I'm using ajax request to get post data from table which has many images & video file. I wanna get post model data with multiple images & videos. but I'm facing problem to show these data in html by jquery scripts.

PHP controller :

```
     public function getposts(){

  //make one array of all table data
  $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->with('postimages')->with('postvideos')->get();
   return response()->json($posts, 200);
  }
```

jQuery scripts:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
  });

//fetch all posts
 getPosts();
 function getPosts(){
   $.ajax({
     url: '/fetch-posts',
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'JSON',
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     cache: false,

     success: function(data){
       
      $('div #postedarea').empty();
      $.each(data, function(key, item){
              $('.post-texts').append(item.text + '<br>');
             $('#postImagesShow').append("<img src='public/images/posts/'" +item['image']+ "/>");

            // $('#postVideo').attr('src', 'public/videos/posts/' + item.video);

            });
          }
        });
      }
        });
</script>
```

Html codes here:

```
<div class="postedareas">
<div class="posttextarea" id="posttextarea">
  <p id="posttext" class="post-texts" >  </p>
</div>

<div class="" id="postImagesShow">
  <img class="img-responsive" id="postImage" src="" />
</div>

<div class="" id="postVideoShow">
  <video id="postVideo" src="" autoplay >

  </video>
</div>
```

Main problem is in images concatenation*

Comment: your question is unclear. Can you provide details of what you wanted and how the above code is working in a different way?

Comment: Images aren't showing on html view page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solutioons of my issues. Answer:

```
 <img src="images/posts/'+image.image+'" class="img-responsive"/>
```